# Quandl on Jupyter Notebook: LimitExceededError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, quandl

I'm having trouble importing and using Quandl on Jupyter notebook. Below is the error message I get. When I do `df = Quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')`, I'm given `NameError: name 'Quandl' is not defined`.

'
[image]

Comment: The error message in the title seems like it is different from what you've posted?

Comment: Two different errors: one when I use `Quandl.get` and another when I use `quandl.get`. Resolved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more digging showed that it was just that Quandl had changed. `quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = <YOUR API KEY HERE>` is required now.